# Login hardware that syncs to web

Tags: mysql, hardware, hardware-interface

I realise this is perhaps pushing the boundaries of what stackoverflow was designed for, however I'm sure someone knows *something* about this.

Basically I'm looking for a piece of hardware, card swiper or physical key, that can be programmed to log someone into a website or load a specific program with a set of variables determined by the key. Basically it needs to hook up to a MYSQL database at some point.

If anyone knows anything at all about how to accomplish this I would be very greatful. My programming knowledge is fairly limited so it needs to be relatively plug and play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start your searches with http://www.yubikey.org/

Comment: Didn't expect someone to get it spot on straight away. Many thanks zerkms.

Comment: @Alex: glad to help ;-) Anyway, I'm working with yubikey as user, not developer, so I cannot give any specific advices more - for me it just works ;-)